# How do I render PDF byte array in Silverlight 5 OOB Application?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I am getting a stream of PDF byte array and I want to render this in my Silverlight OOB Application, I am curious which control should I use to achieve this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a `RadHtmlPlaceHolder` to solve a similar problem:
http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radhtmlplaceholder-overview.html